# how to seach tweets by hashtags and extract a photo for a background image on my site

Tags: node.js, twitter

I have created a nextJS app and deployed it to vercel. I am wondering what would be a good way search for tweets via a certain hashtag most likely a certain date and extract a photo from one of them maybe the one with the most likes, then use that image for a background on a certain page. I haven't set up a database yet.